# elasticsearch query to search 2 different queries on same fields and get results which have the combination of both queries

Tags: elasticsearch

I have 2 parts of query
(a) query
(b) context,
I want to make a query to elasticsearch which give me results on (a), this is mandatory, and the results which have (b) should be boosted.

for example
if the query/(a) is "Inflation rates" and context/(b) is "United States" -- the results should give results only on "Inflation rates" and the results with "United States" should be boosted.

I have tried various concepts of elasticsearch like - bool/should/filter/ but the results are not as exepected.
below I am giving the query template that I am using currently. It gives me results in which query and context are not combined, its just gives docs which either match query or context.
I am using ES 2.4.0

```
{
  "template":{
    "from":"0",
    "size":"10",
    "_source": ["*"],
    "query":{
      "function_score": {
        "query":{
          "bool":{
            "should":[{  
              "match":{
                "display":{
                  "query": "inflation rate",
                  "boost": 2
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "match":{  
                "attributes.definition": {
                  "query": "inflation rate",
                  "boost": 5
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "match":{
                "attributes.topics.name": {
                  "query": "inflation rate",
                  "boost": 5
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "match":{  
                "attributes.titles": {
                  "query": "inflation rate",
                  "boost": 7
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "match":{  
                "attributes.definition": {
                  "query": "United States",
                  "boost": 4
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "match":{
                "attributes.topics.name": {
                  "query": "United States",
                  "boost": 4
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "match":{  
                "attributes.titles": {
                  "query": "United States",
                  "boost": 4
                }
              }
            }],
            "must": [
            {
                "match":{
                  "type":"news"
              }
            }]
          }
        },
        "functions": [{
          "gauss": {
            "attributes.published_ts": {
              "scale": "10d"
            }
          },
          "weight" : 0.1
        }]
      }
    }
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be something like this:
e.g.

```
{           
    "query": {
        "function_score": {
            "filter": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [{  //here can be should, must etc ... This is your first condition.
                        "match": {
                            "attributes.definition": {
                                "query": "inflation rate",
                                "boost": 5
                            }
                        }
                    }, {
                        "match": {
                            "attributes.topics.name": {
                                "query": "inflation rate",
                                "boost": 7
                            }
                        }
                    }]
                }
            },
            "functions": [{  //This is your second condition. Just to give more relevance to the topics with United States.
                "filter": {
                    "term": {
                        "attributes.topics.name": "United States"
                    }
                },
                "weight": 3
            }, {
                "field_value_factor": {
                    "field": "views",
                    "modifier": "log1p"
                }
            }],
            "score_mode": "sum"
        }
    }
}
```

Is just an example, adapt it to your own requirements.

Comment: hi thanks for the example, I tried that example but using must gives empty results most of the time and even if I use should , filter doesn't make any changes to results